# Maximum edges in a square free graph

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

**Square free graph** : Graphs with minimum cycle length greater than 4.

**Question** : What is the maximum number of edges possible for a square free graph $G(V,E)$ given that $|V|$ = n. Is it of the order $O(n^2)$?

How does the answer change if max_degree(G) = d ($>1$)?

**EDIT**: Out of curiosity, what is the maximum number of edges with $n$ vertices, when  we limit the [girth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth) of the graph to $l$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the Abstract ([postscript](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_C4abs.ps)), Zoltan Füredi proves that for $q \ge 25$, a $C_4$-free graph on $q^2 + q + 1$ vertices has at most $\frac{1}{2}q(q+1)^2$ edges, which implies $\frac{1}{2}n^{3/2}$ maximum edges asymptotically (for $n$ nodes). Füredi also describes the graphs which attain his upper bound in terms of finite projective planes. [NB: After viewing [the paper itself](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_C4.pdf) and [references to it](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1144.pdf), the correct upper bound is $\frac{1}{2}q(q+1)^2$ edges, at slight variance with the Abstract.]

His papers are available for PDF and PS download at [this link](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~z-furedi/publ.html), item 148., which includes some longer (published and unpublished) versions.

Comment: Füredi's paper, with its connection to finite projective planes, was a pleasant surprise for me.  In particular I recognized several of his literature citations as ones I'd come across in connection with [this Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442043/covering-with-most-possible-equal-size-subsets-having-pairwise-singleton-interse).

Comment: According to the paper for quadrilateral-free graph of size $n$, the maximum number of edges is $O(n^\frac{3}{2})$. The co-efficient

Comment: Are there any such results for graphs whose girth is strictly greater than $5$

Comment: @Bagaria: I'll take a look, but it seems like a harder problem.  It would make a good Question to post separately.

Comment: @Bagaria: You'll probably find this MathOverflow post, [Largest graphs of girth at least 6](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99770/largest-graphs-of-girth-at-least-6), of interest.  It tabulates the maximum size (number of edges) for given order (number of vertices), though it cautions the values are not well checked, and the Question is about whether a bipartite graph exists that attains the maximum number.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of edges in *any* finite simple graph is of the order $O(n^2)$ so your guess is true, I suppose, but trivially so.

Anyway, your question lies in the area of "extremal graph theory." There is a book by Bollobás with that title which I haven't read but would likely be a good place to start. There is also a chapter in [Diestel's](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/) book which might be helpful to you.

In terms of your particular question, a quick google search found the following paper: ["Extremal graphs of girth 5" by Garnick, Kwong and Lazebnik](http://www.math.udel.edu/~lazebnik/papers/techrep.pdf)

Comment: Also, Füredi, Z.: On the number of edges of quadrilateral-free graphs. *J. Comb. Theory Ser. B* 68(1), 1–6 (1996)

Comment: @Casteels: In the introduction section of the paper "Extremal Graphs of Girth Five", the answer seems to be asymptotically ~ *n^{3/2}. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah looks like it.

Comment: Note that "girth 5" implies $C_3$-free as well as $C_4$-free.