# Reiman theorem in extremal graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I need a source where I can find a proof of Reiman's theorem:

If the graph G is quadrilateral($C_4$)-free, then

$$|E(G)| \leq \frac{|V(G)|}{4}(1 + \sqrt{4\cdot|V(G)| - 3})$$

Here is the idea of the proof:

Consider the set of ordered triplets
$$F= \{(u, v, w) : uv \in E(G), uw \in E(G)\}$$
$$|F| = \sum_{u \in V(G)}(d_G(u)(d_G(u) - 1))$$
On the other hand, as $G$ doesn't have $C_4$, then *(can someone explain this inequality?)*
$$|F| \leq n(n - 1)$$ where $n = |V(G)|.$ 

This part is already clear to me:
Each triplet is defined by its $2$ ends $u$ and $w$, you can choose these $2$ vertices in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways. These triplets are ordered, so we are getting the maximum capacitance of $F$ is $2\binom{n}{2}$. And, therefore, the above inequality holds.
Then, using [Cauchy–Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

we're getting full proof of the theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few links to papers in the answers to this question that might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571823/maximum-edges-in-a-square-free-graph

Comment: Béla Bollobás Extremal Graph Theory (1978), section 6.2, pp. 309-313  gives a proof. If this isn't easily available to you, I can try to summarize it when I get a free moment.

Comment: Thank you, @PerryIverson. But I couldn't find there this theorem exactly.

Comment: @Heghine At the bottom of page 313, Bollobás notes that Theorem 2.3 has this consequence. I believe it's a consequence of Theorem 2.3 together with Theorem 2.6(i).

Comment: I'm interested in this proof but don't have access to this book.  Is it easy to give a quick intuition about how to view the graph ?  Or just the starting point  ?

Comment: @manuellafond,
(http://books.google.am/books?id=q2MAF1vYuWQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)
here is the book.

Comment: @manuellafond, I've also added the idea of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to determine, for each ordered pair of vertices $v$, $w \in V(G)$, how many vertices $u \in V(G)$ are such that $(u, v, w) \in F$.

Our assumption that $G$ is $C_4$-free means that for every ordered pair $v$, $w \in V(G)$, there exists at most one vertex $u$ such that $uv$, $uw \in E(G)$.  This is because if there existed distinct $v$, $w$, $u$, $u' \in V(G)$ such that $uv$, $uw$, $u'v$, $u'w \in E(G)$, then $u$, $u'$, $v$, and $w$ would form a copy of $C_4$, a contradiction.

It follows that $|F|$ is at most the number of ordered pairs of vertices of $G$.  That is,
$$|F| \leq 2\binom{n}{2} = n(n - 1),$$
as we wanted to show.