# All possible sequences satisfying equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Let $21x_{i+3}+20x_{i+2}+19x_{i+1}=x_i^2$, where $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^+$, and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $n>3$ (indices are taken mod $n$). Find all $\{x_i\}$ satisfying this equation.

Taking $\mod{2}$ and $\mod{3}$ tells us a little bit about the nature of the sequences but I haven't been able to get any further.

Comment: How can you take mod $2$ and $3$ when the $x_i$ are real numbers?

Comment: Is $x_i = 0,$ for all $i$ a valid sequence?  Also, (and you are not going to like this), my first approach is to express $x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7,$ and $x_8$ in terms of $x_1, x_2, x_3$, and **stretch my intuition**, seeing where this leads, looking for a **pattern**.

Comment: Also $x_i=60$ for all $i$ works for any $n$. In general $\min_ix_i\leq60\leq\max_ix_i$.

Comment: @YiFan Admittedly, it didn't reveal too much.

Comment: @user2661923 I tried this for a long time, didn't find a pattern :(

Comment: @Servaes This is true, and I see why. I'm trying to characterize all of the solutions though.

Comment: In general, the whole point of the site is that the person who posts the query should show his work **in the query**.  If after posting, he does more work, he should also show that.  Whether his work leads anywhere close to a solution is **totally irrelevant**.  A classic example is a query that I posted, where although all my work was wasted, I showed my work:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843823/revisit-456-handshakes-among-91-people

Comment: I disagree with user2661923, I think enough context is shown (even though I really don't understand what you mean by mod $2$ and $3$).

Comment: @YiFan +1 : fair point.  So, if I understand you correctly, you agree with the objective standard that context is needed, but for this particular query, disagree with my *subjective* view that work hasn't really been shown.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, that's accurate.