# Maximum edges in graph with no triangles is complete bipartite

Tags: graph-theory

I know that Mantel's theorem says that the maximum number of edges in a graph with no 3-cycles is $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.
How can I prove that a graph with no 3-cycles and the maximum number of edges is necessarily $K_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor , \lceil n/2 \rceil}$?

I have tried assuming equality in the inductive proof of Mantel's theorem, so for any edge, its endpoints together are incident with EXACTLY k−1 other edges, so proving the inductive hypothesis provides equality rather than an upper bound, but I am lost on how to go further.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that if $G$ has the maximum edges on $n$ vertices and no $3$-cycles, then for any three vertices $x,y,z$ if edge $xy$ exists, then either $xz$ or $yz$ exists. This implies you should be looking at complete bipartite graphs.

From there show $K_{n/2,n/2}$  maximizes edges among complete bipartite graphs. (I'm not sure how to get ceiling and floor functions)

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to derive this from Mantel's theorem

Comment: The above is essentially a proof of mantel's theorem as it is easy to find the number of edges in a complete bipartite graph, so this technique proves mantel's theorem and answers your question in one shot.

Comment: How about an odd cycle with length $>3$?

Comment: @NP-hard This [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571823/maximum-edges-in-a-square-free-graph) has some answers for that. I'm not sure if there is a nice result like the $C_{3}$ where we know exactly which graph attains the maximum, as the proof idea I gave is a special case of Turan's theorem for complete graphs, since $C_{3} = K_{3}$.

Comment: Misread what you wrote, thought you said any cycle. I don't know about odd cycles either though.

Comment: @Ben: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is `\lfloor x \rfloor`; $\lceil x \rceil$ is `\lceil x \rceil`. Both can be autosized; e.g., $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$ is `\left \lfloor \frac{n}2 \right \rfloor`.