# Proof of $m \leqslant n \times \frac{\sqrt{4n-3} + 1}{4}$ in a graph with no cycle with length 4. (m: edges, n: vertices)

Tags: graph-theory

I have faced a problem and do not know how to prove the following.

> In a graph with no cycles with length $4$, prove that
> $$m \leqslant n \times \frac{\sqrt{4n-3} + 1}{4}$$
> where $m$ is the number of edges and n is the number of vertices.

I tried to count number of paths with length $2$ and relate it to $m$, but couldn't consider the graph has no cycle with length $4$ in the equation.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{4n-3} + 1}{4}$ is a root of $4 x^2 - 2 x + 1=n$ if that helps.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin You mean $4 x^2 -2x + 1 = 0$ ?

Comment: [No](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E2%E2%88%922x%2B1%3Dn).

Comment: Some ideas might be gleaned from the previous Question [Maximum edges in a square free graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571823/maximum-edges-in-a-square-free-graph).

Comment: Your question is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611337/discrete-maths-graphs/2612907#2612907).

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks a lot Alex, I hadn't seen that post previously.