# Number of subsets of the same size and pairwise intersecting in at most one point

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

For any set $X$ of size $n \geqslant 4$, what is the maximum cardinality of a family $\mathscr F$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\vert A \vert =4$ for all $A \in \mathscr F$, and $\vert A \cap B \vert \leqslant 1$ for all distinct $A,B \in \mathscr F$? More generally, for any $1 \leqslant m \leqslant n$, what is the maximum size of a family $\mathscr F$ of subsets of $\{1,,\ldots,n\}$ such that $\vert A \vert = m$ for all $A \in \mathscr F$, and $\vert A \cap B \vert \leqslant m$ for all distinct $A,B \in \mathscr F$?

Comment: Do you mean $|A \cap B| \leq 1$ in the last line, instead of $\leq m$?

Comment: I agree that some context would be helpful for this problem.  Closely related:  [Covering with most possible equal size subsets having pairwise singleton intersections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442043/covering-with-most-possible-equal-size-subsets-having-pairwise-singleton-interse)

Comment: As I think @user1001001 noticed, with its current phrasing your more general problem, in which $|A\cap B| \le m$, is easily solved by taking $\mathscr F$ to be all $\binom{n}{m}$ of the $m$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  So presumably you have something different in mind?

Comment: Yes, I meant $|A \cap B | \leqslant 1$ in the last line. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On page number 190 (Section 13.6) of the book "Extremal Combinatorics, Second Edition" by Jukna, the following result, attributed to Frankl and Wilson, is proved:

If $L\subset \mathbb{N}$ is a finite set of integers and if $F$ is a family of subsets of an $n$ element set such that for all $A, B \in F$, $A \neq B$, $|A\cap B| \in L$, then $|F|\leq \sum_{i = 0}^{|L|}\binom{n}{i}$.

Comment: Applied to the first part of the Question, where $L = \{0,1\}$, this gives the upper bound $|\mathscr F| \le 1 + n + n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: Thank you. However, we need the additional constraint $|A|=|B|=k$ (e.g., $k=4$), which certainly reduces the cardinality of the upper bound.

Comment: @user462634 Possibly, although its not immediately obvious that the bound can be pushed down in the case when cardinalities are equal.